# What does it mean when `Ex` is added to a function/method name?

Tags: winapi, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

I don't work with the Windows API much, but I've seen it used there as well as occasionally in a codebase here at work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yup, they wanted to improve (Extend) the API and keep a similar name so it was likely that the programmer would move to the new version.

Notable is GetVersionEx() to get the Windows version, pretty painful for a while with a nasty chicken-and-egg problem.

The record keeper is the National Language Support team who have several ExEx versions, like EnumCalendarInfoExEx.  Unsurprising, culture moves even faster than software.  No ExExEx as of yet.

Comment: *Most* `Ex` functions are supposed to take arguments via a `struct` whose first member is the size of the `struct`.  The size acts as a version number and is supposed to allow the function to be extended further if necessary without the need for additional `Ex` suffixes.

Answer (score 10):

It's usually done as a way of changing the parameters to a function in an API without breaking existing client code.  Old code can continue to use the previous version, while new code can take advantage of the new features offered by the Ex version.

Answer (score 6):

It's a naming convention that simply indicates the function is an **extended** version of an original.

Comment: Yes, this is to provide backwards compatibility - Windows hardly ever obsoletes an API function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I guess it stands for extended.