# What is the "foo" vs. "foo1" naming convention in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've seen some APIs that have a `def foo` and then a slightly different `def foo1`, but I can't figure out what this means other than "`foo1` is kind of like `foo` but slightly different." It reminds me of "Ex" ( [What does "Ex" stand for in Windows API function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039054/what-does-ex-stand-for-in-windows-api-function-names) )

I'm guessing this is a reference to a Haskell/FP or mathematical convention, is it just foo-prime?

Is there any meaning implied (does `foo1` have to relate to `foo` in some specific way) or is it more "I needed two similar functions and overloading was ambiguous, screw it, let's put a 1 on the end"? Should I assume anything beyond "these two functions are somehow related"?

Comment: +1 "some APIs" is not much to go on. Perhaps these are crap APIs, designed by morons?

Comment: well I was thinking if it's an actual convention people would know it without knowing the specific API ;-) I'm looking at for example Play Promise has extend/extend1, Play Iteratee has fold/fold1, and I was just reading this morning about an example in scalaz that I'm not personally familiar with.

Comment: If nobody knows examples the answer could be "this is not a well-known convention" I think.

Answer (score 2):

The example I can think of is `rep` and `rep1` in `scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers`, where `rep` is any number of repeats and `rep1` is for 1 or more. There's also a `repN` method for N repeats, so here the meaning of the `1` suffix is pretty obvious.

Comment: so in that case 1 means 1, rather than "prime" I guess

Answer (score 1):

I think that context is probably everything here. The only example I can think of this is the `foldl1` method in **scalaz**. As the library authors would no doubt point out, what the method actually does it completely transparent from looking at the types themselves:

```
trait MA[M[_], A] {
  def foobar(f: (A, A) => A)(implicit FoldableM: Foldable[M]): Option[A]
}
```

However, in this case, it's clearly a *special form* of `foldl`, that is, *fold left but use the 1st element as a seed rather than an explicitly provided value*. Hence `foldl1` is sensible and intuitive in context.

You say you have seen this a few times: can you point out other occurrences?

Comment: Here's a fold1: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Iteratee.scala#L51 and an extend1: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/concurrent/Promise.scala#L53

Answer (score 0):

Scala's contains types like Function and Tuple, which have a family of types, each member being named for the number of arguments it takes.

```
Function1[T1] => R
Function2[T1, T2] => R

Tuple1[T1]
Tuple2[T1, T2]
```

In both cases the name of the type must be distinct and using the number of arguments is a great way to describe the type (Function4 is the type of a function that takes 4 arguments, Tuple3 is the type of a Tuple containing 3 items).

As the other answers have said, it helps to have some context but it could be that your examples are inspired (rightly or wrongly) by these choices in the standard library.