# Adding -Ex to the name of a type in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I've noticed a pattern recently in our codebase at work, where most of our model class have a name such as User, and there is an inheriting type that has extra fields on it called UserEx.  I've also noticed this in the C# async CTP where they put the additional static methods for Task in a class called TaskEx (due to technical restrictions, since they couldn't alter the existing library).  Talking to someone at work, I learned that -Ex classes exist to optimize network transfers (you can pull only the bare minimum if you need).  My question, then, is what does -Ex stand for?  The only thing I can think of is possibly "Extra".

Comment: Could also be "extension" - and with a little searching on this forum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963374/what-does-it-mean-when-ex-is-added-to-a-function-method-name (although this is for the Windows API, I assume people have been using the naming convention since)

Comment: I will go with Extended , Micorosoft com used this notation as well :)

Comment: It's probably part of their naming convention for example at work they want us to prefix any class that we write as clsSomeClasee.cs make sense

Comment: Thanks @C.Evenhuis, extension or extended makes a lot more sense than extra.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The other answers all got it correct: the `Ex` suffix stands for "extended". It's a way of introducing a new class or method without obsoleting or removing the old one, a common way of retaining backwards compatibility while introducing new features.

The Windows API does this all over the place, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963535/366904).

Hans hints at the problem with this approach in his explanation: **it doesn't scale**. What if you want to extend an "extended" function? Do you call it `FunctionExEx`? That looks stupid.

So stupid, in fact, that Microsoft's own coding guidelines for .NET (subjective though they are) [specifically recommend *against* appending `Ex` to a type](http://books.google.com/books?id=39d1wZ598ecC&pg=PT100). Instead, if you must do this, you should use a number:

```
MyType
MyType2   // modified version
MyType3   // oh wait, we had to modify it again!
```

Blaming this on poor planning as [dowhilefor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8592716/366904) tries to do is a bit premature. When writing real world applications and frameworks, you often need to *ship*. That means getting out a quick-and-dirty version of the function that *works*. Later, you decide this is a poor design and something needs to change. Rather than throwing up your hands and completely re-writing (producing giant delays and obsoleting all of the old code), you introduce a new type with a different name. Hindsight is always 20/20.

Comment: Great post. Btw, 20/20 is normal vision, hindsight probably gives you much more than normal vision - https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080215115045AATahKe

Answer (score 5):

Ending a new class or method or type in `Ex` is a naming convention, and like any naming convention, it is subject to the whims of those implementing it.

There are no hard and fast rules, and it is no more or less correct than appending `2` to the end of the class (or `Extra`, or `More`, or `DidntWantToMessWithThePublicApi`).

As for why it is used, Microsoft has a long history of using it to provide a revision to an existing API without breaking older code. You can find examples of this [in classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984294.aspx), [in methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [in structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363163%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can also find different examples, [which instead use `2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692720%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that the .NET team no longer does/recommends this, in part because of the problems experienced by the Win32 team. It simply doesn't scale in the event you want to "extend" something twice or three times.

Comment: Oh I agree, *"it is subject to the whims of those implementing it"*. I didn't intend on providing conformance advice.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for "Extension" or "Extended", as far as I know. It's a common suffix to when you need to add functionnality to something that you can't change. A good example was the various -Ex functions in the Win32 APIs, which were added because C does not support function overloading.

Answer (score 1):

This practice is NOT industry-standard.  I'll admit I do it myself, but it's mostly vestigial emulation of some of the old win32 kernel functions.  for example, they initially had a "beginthread" C function and later created another new-and-improved "begintreadEx".

I would suggest that you start using the [Deprecated] attribute to signal to other coders (or yourself) to stop using the old function in favor of the new one.  That has more intrinsic meaning.

Long story short -- **you should name classes & functions based on what they are or do**, and try to avoid pseudo-meaningful prefixes/suffixes that create confusion such as this.  That is the industry-standard approach.

Comment: What happens if the two functions *are* and *do* [basically] the same thing? Appending something to the end is a fairly self-documenting way of indicating that one is an extended or modified version of the first. The suffixes are not meaningless in context. What would you name `BeginThreadEx`?

Comment: Most of the time in C# you can keep the existing method name and just create a new overload (with different parameters).

Comment: i rather like BeginThreadEx since at least it was consistent w/ the other win32 kernel functions.  I meant what I said as a guideline, not a hard rule.  I don't think there's a recipe one can follow to always name functions well, there's no substitute for thinking particularly about your particular function -- and recognize that being consistent (even if not industry-standard) has a lot of value.

Comment: @AlanR - the -Ex classes, in our code base, do not deprecate the old ones.  Instead they provide extended functionality.  As I said in the original post, User is for sending bare minimum, whereas UserEx is for sending more information when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought possibly:

- external
- extricated
- simply 'ex' (as in 'out of' or 'beyond')

Comment: To complete your list: an alternative to obsolete - "I used to date `classNameEx`, now I'm with `className`" :P

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, i think it means "We didn't plan this feature long enough, didn't thought about the changed requirements, and we have to deal with this now close to the deadline". Of course this is not always the case, but everytime i find a class with Ex i try to figure out why it was introduced and not properly added into the framework. For me its mostly like `// HACK:`
This only counts for our code, if it is in a framework i "hope" thats just naming convention.
What it could mean was already answered, my guess was always "Extended"