# what does suffix _ex mean in function name

Tags: winpcap

Recently,i was reading the tutorial of winpcap. But the following words confused me. 
“Why do we use pcap_next_ex() instead of the old pcap_next()? Because pcap_next() has some drawbacks. ”
Isn't ex means old?
I will be glad if someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ex" stands for "extended". This is a common practice in some libraries, and I think Win32 is the main notorius example thereof.

See this for reference on the Win32 case:
[Adding -Ex to the name of a type in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592579/adding-ex-to-the-name-of-a-type-in-net)